# How to append text to JTextArea from main function int java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want to append some text to `JTextArea` from main function, but it doesn't work.

I am appending text from `init()` and from `main()`, but only text from `init()` appears on `JTextArea`.

```
public class Test extends JApplet{

    private static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    public void init() {   

        panel.setLayout(null); 
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300)); 
        this.add(panel);

        textArea.setBounds(20, 150, 350, 100);
        panel.add(textArea);

        setTextArea("BBBB");
    }

    public static void setTextArea(String text){
        textArea.append(text);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        setTextArea("AAAAA");
    }   

}
```

I'm getting textarea just with "BBBB".

**UPDATE**

I have one more function. I am calling it from `init()`, text is appending and everything is fine. But if I put a line `setTextArea("some text");`
 after line `clientSocket = new Socket(address, port);`, text won't append.

```
 private static void connetToServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            //address = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "localhost";
            //port = args.length > 1 ? Integer.parseInt(args[1]) : 4444;
            //System.out.println(address + ' ' + port);
            setTextArea("some text");
            clientSocket = new Socket(address, port);
            output = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            input = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            inputLine = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
        } 
        catch( IOException e){
            setTextArea("Can't connet to server");
            System.exit(0);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting "BBBB" appended to your text area because the `init` method is used as an entry point for `applets` and `servlets`.

Your class `extends JApplet` which is a subclass of `java.applet.Applet` meaning it will use `init` and not `main` (which is instead used as an entry point for applications).

Comment: Thank you, but I added one more question. Can you ask?

Comment: Is your `clientSocket` getting initialized correctly? Are you getting an error/exception preventing your code from continuing? You have the parameters commented out in your code example. The chances are it it is failing to create a new `Socket` for `clientSocket`.

Comment: No, client connects to server correctly. I am getting parameters from JTextFields, it is old version in comments.

Comment: If you step through your code line-by-line in debug mode, what happens when you move over the line `clientSocket = new Socket(address, port);`? Does it error at all? There shouldn't be any reason why it wouldn't append the text other than it not actually reaching that line.

Comment: Yes, you were tight. I am getting such exeption 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:4444" "connect,resolve")